# Searching through 1,000 Contacts in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I have successfully written a program that searches through a user's contacts but it feels very inefficient. It uses nested for and if statements and is overall very cluttered. When I run it on my simulator, it works fine but it's painfully slow.

Does anyone know a better way to write this?

This is what I currently have:

```
import UIKit
import Contacts

class ChatViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var contactTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var contactNameView: UIView!

let contactStore = CNContactStore()
var contacts = [CNContact]()
let keys = [CNContactFormatter.descriptorForRequiredKeys(for: .fullName), CNContactPhoneNumbersKey] as [Any]



@IBAction func contactTextFieldChanged(_ sender: Any) {
    if contactTextField.text != nil {
        contactTableView.isHidden = false

        let request = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: keys as! [CNKeyDescriptor])
        do {
            try contactStore.enumerateContacts(with: request){
                (contact, stop) in
                self.contacts.append(contact)
                for familyName in contact.familyName{
                    for givenName in contact.givenName{
                        for phoneNumber in contact.phoneNumbers {
                            if String(describing: phoneNumber) != ""{
                            if String(describing: phoneNumber) == self.contactTextField.text || String(describing: givenName) == self.contactTextField.text || String(describing: familyName) == self.contactTextField.text{
                                if let number = phoneNumber.value as? CNPhoneNumber, let label = phoneNumber.label {
                                    let localizedLabel = CNLabeledValue<CNPhoneNumber>.localizedString(forLabel: label)
                                    print("\(contact.givenName) \(contact.familyName) tel:\(localizedLabel) -- \(number.stringValue)")
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            print(contacts)
        } catch {
            print("unable to fetch contacts")
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `contact.familyName.contains(self.contactTextField.text)` instead of one level of iteration.

Comment: That gives me the error "Cannot convert value of type 'String?' to expected argument type 'String.Element' (aka 'Character')". Any idea how to fix?

Comment: Why not create a predicate, NSPredicate, for your fetch request that corresponds to the search you want to do?

Comment: I don't know what that is...

Comment: It's like a filter that you can create programatically, it should be more efficient than filtering in your own loops. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/AdditionalChapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001798-SW1

Comment: That looks like it could work. I'm not exactly sure how to use it with CNContact but at least I know what to look for now. Thanks @JoakimDanielson